# Require SQL Server on client computer

Tags: sql-server

I am developing an application in Visual Studio 2010 that has a SQL Server database in it. My question is that, when I will install this application on the client computer, does that computer need to have SQL Server installed to work properly?

Comment: You need to clarify your question a bit; is the application connecting to a remote SQL Server database?  How do you currently connect?

Comment: Your application will have to be able to connect *some* SQL Server instance - but whether that's on the client's own machine, or whether that client has a central SQL Server machine to connect to - that's entirely up to you and your clients.

Answer (score 4):

> I am developing an application in Visual Studio 2010 that has a SQL Server database in it.

I make a resturant that has customers. Do I need to buy meat for the food?

Seriously, YOU SHOULD KNOW.

Is it a Client/Server application then maybe no, the client does not need sql server. Maybe it does, depends what the clients do, but it is QUITE normal for only the server having SQL Server installed. Only the programmer (that would be you, in case you wonder) knows what he is programming.

If it is a normal client application and it uses SQL Server, then how you think it can use SQL Server if it is not installed? Kind of cooking a real Argentinian steak without using meat. SURE you have to have it installed.

Comment: +1 for all the meat references. Almost a -1 because you've made me hungry for dinner, which is still a few hours away. :-)

Comment: Well more precisely, application will be installed on a single computer, No client server architecture. I am using C#, VS2010.

Comment: THen yes, you need to install sql server to use sql server. Sort of circular, isn't it?